# HTML Scraper for Yahoo! Finance returning wrong value using lxml and requests

Tags: python, html, request, lxml

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN?p=AMZN&.tsrc=fin-srch')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

peRatio = tree.xpath('//span[@class="Trsdu(0.3s) "] [@data-reactid="92"]/text()')
peRatio
```

The above outputs the expected results if I had written [@data-reactid="92"] which gives me 2,075.74. Does anyone know why this is happening? I was expecting to get 81.48 which can be seen in the source code for the AMZN stock.

EDIT: I discovered something odd.. What I was seeing in the HTML script was consistently off by 26. So when I used [@data-reactid="66"] I got what I was looking for. Similarly, 118-92 = 26. This carried over to several other cases. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: Looks like a bug. You can omit the class and just do the data-reactid and it gives the wrong answer.  Your reading of the html is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to be a bug? The data-reactid values are sorted in ascending order and don't match the text values of the corresponding spans. So the text values of the spans are printed in document order while the data-reactid values are sorted then they are matched incorrectly.  IE 15 returns 1,636.40 which is really 41.

```
<span class="Trsdu(0.3s) " data-reactid="41">1,636.40</span>
```

I'm reviewing my old code to see if we can fix your xpath to work properly. Here is how I saw the problem. Will update in a few hours when I return if I find a proper solution or delete this if someone else has an answer.

```
print(tree.xpath('//span[@class="Trsdu(0.3s) "]/text()'))
print(tree.xpath('//span[@class="Trsdu(0.3s) "]/@data-reactid'))

['1,636.40', '1,628.18', '1,639.00 x 900', '1,640.25 x 900', '3,148,824', '6,293,333', '806.108B', '1.71', '81.48', '20.14', 'N/A', '2,075.74']
['15', '20', '25', '30', '43', '48', '56', '61', '66', '71', '87', '92']
```